Can I plumb 2 tankless gas hot water heater in line ( series)?
Can I plumb in 1st tank and set it at 85* and then the 2nd at 120*+? We have artesian water in there northern Idaho and have 42-55* water. Makes it hard on only 1 heater to go ALL the way to 120+ with any good gpm. Of course ALL heaters show MAX number of flow at only a 20* rise, not anywhere near ANY actual area of usage.

Normally with very cold feed water you would just get a single tankless WH with a very large BTU/h rating. These come up to 199 kBTU/h. If you already have one heater rated at say 180 kBTU/h and this is not enough, then maybe you might consider a second heater rated at 180 kBTU/h. and put it in series, but I have never heard of this being done. If you have very cold inlet water, you might have to use a gas fired tank to get hot water at a high flow when you want that. Does the water have a high mineral content?

You mention "wire"? Are you planning on electric tankless WH or gas fired tankless (natural gas or LPG)? If you have very cold inlet water and want flow for multiple uses at one time, then electric resistance would require more power than you would likely have available. Dividing up the heating between two electric tankless WHs would not reduce the total power (and current in A) required.

120v for ignition and control for gas fired tankless heater. Hard water, that I have a "pre-filter" on and at least yearly cycle vinegar through. Not looking to replace existing unit just want to up the flow to whole house to closer to what manufacturer says is max.

You should either get a bigger/better tankless water heater that can handle the full flow rate and temperature rise desired, or put in a tank.
Seriously. Tankless is a fantastic concept, and with gas it can work reasonably well as you don't have quite the same peak demand issues as with electric. But if you are at the point of installing two heaters, not for different parts of the house but for sequential heating, this doesn't seem to be a workable solution.
Unless you have a need for continuous usage at well over 40 gallons per hour, a tank is likely to work better for you. A typical (based on Rheem, but they're all pretty similar - not much in a standard gas tank water heater) 50 gallon model is rated at 40,000 BTUs and 40 gallons per hour at a 90 F rise, with 77 gallons the first hour. If that's not enough, get two tanks and double your capacity. (Due to regulations, tank water heaters larger than 50 gallons cost a lot more.)
Compare that to a 200,000 BTU (OK, 199,900 BTU - I suspect another regulation getting in the way there - all brands have 199k but not 200k residential tankless). Using Rheem again as an example, that gets you 3.7 GPM at a 90 F rise. So yes, that will give you over 200 gallons an hour. But do you really need that much? If your usage is more like 2 GPM for 10 minutes, then another 2 GPM for 10 minutes, etc., a tank will do just fine, and a tank will also do fine if you have 4 GPM (two showers at once or one plus laundry or kitchen, etc.) for a limited time, where the tankless may start to have issues.
Tankless does not save a lot of energy. It saves a little (one Home Depot brochure I saw comparing different types had it at $1,100 savings over 12 years, so ~ $100 per year). It does not generally save a lot on installation. A big factor to consider is your gas supply. 200k BTU is not super-huge, but you do need to make sure you have the capacity if you want to install effective tankless - it sounds like right now you have a smaller tankless water heater.
